# A polynomial with non-negative integer coefficients assuming prime values up to a given value of the argument

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Given a positive integer $N$ does there exist a polynomial $P$ with non-negative integer coefficients such that $P(n)$ is a prime number for $1\leq n <N$ and $P(N)$ is a composite number? Also, if for given $N$ we know that such a polynomial exists can we algorithmically find an example?

Examples

- $N=1: P(n)=4$
- $N=2: P(n)=n+2$
- $N=3: P(n)=n+1$
- $N=4: P(n)=n^2+n+1$
- $N=40:P(n)=n^2+n+41.$

Comment: i upvoted; interesting question, nicely presented.

Comment: What we can say for sure that at some point a composite number must appear. So the part with "$P(N)$ composite" is guaranteed.

Comment: For the last polynomial, we have $N=40$ since for $N=40$ , the polynomial gives a composite value already.

Comment: The Green Tao theorem gives answer "yes" to this question. It states that there are arbitary long arithmetic progressions (which are formed by a one-degree polynomial $p(n)$ with positive integer coefficients and $n$ having the values $1,2,3,\cdots,k$) with all entries being prime numbers.

Comment: @John Omelian This can be adapted to satisfy the OP's condition as below.

Comment: @S.Dolan Thanks for your feedback. You're right. I wasn't thinking it through very well since, as your answer states, you can just start from just before the first composite of any arithmetic sequence of at least $k$ and then go forward $k$ items. As such, I've deleted my comment.

Comment: @John Omelian Good, I'm glad I hadn't misunderstood anything. By the way I did respond to your comment about Lemma 1 on another post - have you looked at that again?

Comment: @S.Dolan If you're referring to this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3514186/x-is-an-infinite-subset-of-mathbb-z-and-t-xy-mid-x-y-in-x-x-neq-y/3517131#comment7234398_3517131), I read what you wrote. Thank you for responding. However, I didn't believe your reply addressed what I was getting at regarding an inconsistency between what the lemma stated and what it actually was for, but decided I wasn't interested in pursuing the issue any further, so I didn't do anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p_1,p_2, ... , p_k$ be a sequence of at least N-1 primes in AP with common difference $d$. The sequence cannot continue generating primes for ever since $p_1+dp_1$ is not prime.

Therefore we can change our starting position in the sequence so there are precisely $N-1$ primes before a composite number is reached. Let $p$ be the first prime in this sequence then the required function is $$P(n)=p-d+dn.$$

Comment: This is certainly correct, but it brings a bit of nuclear fly-swatting to the problem. It'd be interesting to know if there's an elementary proof of the simpler version that removes the exactness constraint: can it be proven that e.g. there's an infinite sequence of coefficients $c_i$ such that the polynomial $P_n(x) = \sum_{i\leq n}c_ix^i$ is prime for $1\leq x\leq n$?

Comment: I think that what you are asking for is far too difficult for it to have an elementary solution.